# Question about graceful restart

Tags: routing, bgp, troubleshooting, redundancy

i do some research on graceful restart for OSPF, BGP, LDP. After i read those RFCs for these protocols, i have a question want to ask that if a router really goes down not restart (i.e. power off...), how can it still forward data????

Best regards,

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Graceful Restart is not designed to maintain forwarding in the event that a router is intentionally shut down; it is only to keep forwarding working long enough to perform a soft reboot on one controller at a time (of two or more controllers), i.e. to let firmware updates take effect.  In effect, the functionality puts a "pause" on routing protocols so that surrounding routers don't panic when a peer isn't responding to BGP/LDP/etc. Then, when the reboot is complete, the peer routers can rebuild just their relationship to get back in sync, instead of reconverging the entire path.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. besides, would you please give me some documents about this problem.